# How do you keep Unity Panel while using Cairo-Dock on 12.10?

Tags: unity, cairo-dock

On Ubuntu 12.04 I was able to keep unity panel (the thing at the top of the screen with the time, log out options, wireless connectivity, battery power details, etc) while not keeping the unity shell (side panel thing with the launchers) and having Cairo-Dock as my launcher of programs. In Ubuntu 12.10 I don't seem to be able to do this. I'm able to use Cairo-Dock without unity shell and panel no problem but I can't seem to get the unity panel from staying while the unity shell (side-panel with launchers and dash) is absent.
basically I want you to tell me how I can re-accomplish that which is in the picture below on Ubuntu 12.10. (this pic from was 12.04)

[image]

Comment: Are in this way, Unity panel and launcher disabled? Or are they simply hidden? I would really have a simple and light DE with OSX menu bar, but sadly in Ubuntu 13.10 classic (gnome-session-flashback), globalmenu-applet seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install cairo-dock, by pasting the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

into terminal. (ctrl+alt+T) Then go to system settings. (By clicking the icon in the far right corner in the unity panel and going down and clicking, 'system settings')

After this go to 'Appearance' under 'Personal' then select, 'Behaviour.' Then click, 'on' to the option of auto-hiding the launcher. After this set the reveal location as, 'Top Left Corner' and set the reveal sensitivity to as small as possible by manually moving it the lever.

Answer (score -1):

please take a look at the wiki, it's all explained:
http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Cairo-Dock%20and%20Unity&lang=en

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.